# Should 'productive sysadmins without root' be listed as a canonical question?

Tags: discussion

Should [Linux: productive sysadmins without root (securing intellectual property)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/753268/linux-productive-sysadmins-without-root-securing-intellectual-property/753295#753295) be listed as a canonical question?

Answer (score 7):

Our current list of canonical questions is meant to serve as a repository of dupe targets for questions that are (relatively) frequently asked.

This particular question is pretty good, maybe even deserving of being shared on social media, but it doesn't seem to me that it's something that we get asked frequently (even if it *should* be).